# You must think that she had or has?

Tags: modal-verbs

Which one is correct?

> 1. You must think that she has the money
> 2. You must think that she had the money

But she doesn't, Isn't the *has* a stative verb? it means that she really **HAS** the money, even though it's false, or the second example works better? But the tenses don't fit each other.

> 3. You must've thought that she had the money

Personally I think the third example is correct but I am not sure.

Would someone explain to me how does *must* work in a sentence?.

Answer (score 1):

All three of your sample sentences are grammatically correct, and have slightly different meanings. Taking these sentences from the point-of-view of the person being talked to:

> You must think that she has the money.

This means that you *at this present time* think that she has the money *at this present time*.

> You must think that she had the money.

This means that you *at this present time* think that she had the money *at some time in the past*.

> You must've thought that she had the money.

This means that you *at some time in the past* thought that she had the money *at some time in the past*.

With regards to using *must*, you just use it to inform that the person or thing referred to has to possess or do the verb referred to. By adding *have* after must, you can use it with verbs in past tense like you have with your third sentence.

Comment: Even if she actually doesn't have the money the first example will still  work?

Comment: Yes, because it's not about whether she has the money, but whether the "you" *believes* she has the money. For any of the sentences it doesn't matter whether she actually had/has the money or not; it's all about whether the "you" believes that she does or did.

Comment: I think what's now confusing OP is that your 2nd blockquoted example has a typo: it should read  *that she **had*** rather than ***has***.